# How do I train tesseract 5 on a custom data set

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm working on my senior project which involves reading the information on a card from a game, to do this I'm using Tesseract 5, but there's a part of the card where the OCR doesn't recognize the numbers (this part is only numbers). I wanted to train it using a bunch of different screenshots of that part but there is very little information on how to do so for tesseract 5.

I was wondering if this is possible or if there are better ways to do this, any help would be appreciated!

(additional info the game is Empires&Puzzles)

I have taken a lot of different screenshots and have a txt file for each picture with the numbers found on the card and I've pretty much just been stuck here.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.